# Program to find the maximum number/factor in a list

Tags: assembly, x86

I have written the following basic assembly program to find the maximum number in a list divisible by a number. Here is what I have thus far:

```
# Program: given a list or integers and a factor
# Find the max number in the list that the factor divides
# For example: INPUT: [3,9,50,27], factor: 3 | OUTPUT: 27
.section .rodata
nums:   .long 3,9,50,27,-1
factor: .long 3

.section .data
cur_value:  .long -1

# first three args: %edi, %esi, %edx
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:

    # SETUP
    # %r8 will store the array index 
    # %r11 will store the max value
    # %esi will store the factor/divisor. 
    mov $0,     %r10d
    mov $0,     %r11d
    mov factor, %esi


loop:
    
    # get current value and store it in %rdi
    # we'll also update our variable for `cur_value`
    mov nums(, %r10d, 4), %edi
    cmp $-1, %edi
    je exit
    movl %edi, cur_value

    # Call the function and increment the aray index
    call is_divisible_by
    inc %r10d

    # if it was NOT divisible (rax = False or 0) jump back to the beginning
    cmp $0, %rax
    je loop

    # if it was divisible, check to make sure it's larger than the current max
    cmp %r11d, cur_value
    jl loop
    mov cur_value, %r11d
    jmp loop
  exit:
    mov %r11d, %edi
    mov $60, %eax
    syscall
    
is_divisible_by:

    # Return 0 (false) if not divisible; 1 (true) if divisible

    # A (dividend, %eax) / B (divisor)
    # dividend needs to first be moved into eax
    mov %edi, %eax 

    # divide by a register, immediate, or memory address
    # this is unsigned (positive), use idiv for signed
    div %esi

    # the resultant integer quotient goes in %eax, and the remainder goes in %edx
    # if %rdx is zero it means A is divisible by B: we don't care about %eax
    mov $0, %eax

    cmp $0, %edx
    jne end
    mov $1, %rax

  end:
    ret
```

It's compiled using:

```
$ as file.s -o file.o && ld file.o -o file
$ ./file; echo $?
# 27
```

Here are a few particular questions related to this:

1. Is it common to use named variables (such as `cur_value` in `.section .data`) or not? I use them while learning a bit so it's easier to view the value of an easily-rememberable entity, i.e., I can just do `x &cur_value` in gdb to see what it is.
2. What is the suggested way to handle an `if` statement. I've tried to do this in the `is_divisible_by` function -- setting it to `$0` by default and then 'overwriting' it if the `true` condition is met. -- but this seems pretty hacky. I suppose another way to do it would be something like:

   ```
     cmp $0, %edx
     je set_true
   set_false:
     mov $0, %eax
     jmp clean_up
   set_true:
     mov $1, %eax
     jmp clean_up
   clean_up:
     ret
   ```
3. Is it common to have end-labels on functions and such? I find myself often adding an `end` or whatever to be able to 'exit' things easily.
4. For labels within a main label (such as `exit` or `end` or `set_true` etc.), what is a good way to name these? I see `gcc` uses something like `.L1029` but that seems not-too-friendly when writing my own and having to remember then.
5. Would any of the above be better done 'on the stack' rather than using registers or named variables? I find it a bit more difficult to use the stack than registers as you cannot do something like `mov mem1, mem2`
6. Finally, how could I extract the `is_divisible_by` function into another file and call it from within this main `file.s` file?

Comment: As stated in the [guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please do not edit the question after you have received an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two independent conditions that must be satisfied before updating `cur_val`.

1. The number must be divisible by `factor`
2. The number must be larger than `cur_val`

If the first test fails, you don't bother doing the second test.

How many instruction (or better cycles) does it take to do each test?

Given a long non-monotonic list, you may save considerable time simply by reversing these two tests.

Comment: sorry I've updated the question. The elements in the list can be in any order not just a sorted list. Also, regarding `How many instruction (or better cycles) does it take to do each test` -- how can I find out how many cycles a section of code takes? I'm very new to assembly and have always wondered about that?

Comment: That is a very difficult question, and can depends on CPU version, cache, CPU -vs- Memory bus clock speed, and so on.  You'd have to consult the CPU spec sheet, motherboard configuration. But a fair guess is `cmp` & `jl` takes way less than `call is_divisible_by`, `cmp` & `je` will take.

Comment: I see. Do you want to add a bit of code to your answer with how you'd suggest implementing it?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Sorry, no.  I'm reasonably proficient reading code, but writing assembly I haven't done since 80486 days.

Comment: @AJNeufedl -- I see, ok thanks for the feedback though!